# Sometimes, my PC don't turn off after shutting down

Tags: ubuntu, power-supply, sleep, shutdown, hibernate

When shutting down, hibernate or going to sleep, sometimes the power supply remains on (I can hear the fan).  I must turn it off by pressing and holding the on/off button for 5 seconds.  If it went to sleep I lose the session (of course).

The PC is a desktop, not a notebook.

Everything shuts down, then I hear a click from a relay or something in the power supply.  where everything goes ok, that's the final sound.  But when it fails, the fan remains on.

It's not random.  When it fails, it fails always for many days.  And when it works, it works for many days.  Perhaps it toggle after some OS update.

I changed the power supply (not for this reason), and it continues the same.

I use Ubuntu 18, but it was happening for many versions before.

Any suggestion?

Comment: perhaps you will need to share your motherboard type.. i'm not really acquitanced with *nix series for desktop, does it have anything like power configuration?

Comment: are you running any backup software that might stall a log off or shut down process?

Comment: Do you mean **fan** instead of fun ?

Comment: Try shutdown your system using [init](http://www.agr.unideb.hu/~agocs/informatics/11_e_unix/unixhelp/unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgia215.html?init+8) runlevel commands. Type this at terminal : **`init 0`** to shutdown machine OR **`init 6`** to reboot machine. Or you can even use [shutdown](https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) command.

Comment: @BagusTesa, I will, as soon I get to that PC.  Thank you.

Comment: @SirAdelaide, not that I'm aware of.  I'll appreciate it if you can tell me some way to verify this, but I believe there's no easy way.  Thanks.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus, yes, fan, thanks, already edited.  I'll try init.

Comment: If it's a hardware problem, it might require a hardware solution.  That the problem is intermittent makes me think that it isn't likely to be a configuration issue.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus, init 0 didn't do anything different, fan remains on.  I believe this is something related the specific way the driver ask the motherboard to turn off.  I am reluctant to upgrade the motherboard firmware.